# "Overwrite" MessageBox Template

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, messagebox

I have already a big application, with lot of MessageBox inside.

I would like to make a template for all MessageBoxes (Background, Border etc...).
Is it possible through the App.xaml to do that easily, or do I necessarly think to make my own custom MessageBox, and so replace all MessageBoxes of my solution?
I tried in App.xaml but I cannot see a possibility to set TargetType="MessageBox".

Comment: I think this is not possible. It's a native control. But you can create your own very easy. You can use a customized  `Window` and then show it modal by calling `Windows.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @BionicCode In fact that's what I will do, now I can understand it is not possible, I began using templates yesterday, and want to use only that for all my project cause easier later to make modifies. For now I could do almost everything, still meeting issues for ComboBox, and MessageBox. But for MessageBox seems there is no way to do that.

Comment: @BionicCode May I just delete the question, or may you make an answer so I could mark the question as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible. It's a native Windows control. But you can create your own very easy. You can use a customized `Window` and then show it modal by calling `Window.ShowDialog()`.